# Appirater doesn't work for me? Although I followed the instructions and doublechecked

Tags: iphone, ios, rate, appirater

I want my app to ask the user to rate/write review in the app store, thats why I tried to implement Appirater from Arash Payan. But it simply doesn't work - no warning is shown, doesn't matter how often I try.

What I did:

- downloaded Appirater from
  https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/
- followed theses steps provided in the ReadMe:

  1. Add the Appirater code into your project
  2. Add the CFNetwork and SystemConfiguration frameworks to your project
  3. Call [Appirater appLaunched:YES] at the end of your app delegate's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.
  4. Call [Appirater appEnteredForeground:YES] in your app delegate's applicationWillEnterForeground: method.
  5. (OPTIONAL) Call [Appirater userDidSignificantEvent:YES] when the user does something 'significant' in the app.
  6. Finally, set the APPIRATER_APP_ID in Appirater.h to your Apple provided software id.

I also changed the alert message, because my language is not english. 
I changed the times of use to 5 times...

What did I do wrong/how can I fix it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your app delegate and see where the code of appirater is called. Try to follow through the code so you can see why it does not show anything. I would think appirater will not only count times, but might use the date to trigger it's pop up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea why, but after doing a software update to my iPhone, cleaning the project MANUALLY, it worked again!

Answer (score 6):

We had a similar problem when first implementing Appirater. The solution, while obvious when it dawned on us, was strangely not addressed in any of the answers we came across, so this is just to help those who have similar difficulties.

Appirater will not show any messages if you are not connected to a network, or if it cannot reach the app store for any reason - even in debug mode. Again it makes total sense - except that maybe debug mode should tell you that you're not connected, or that it cannot reach the app store, but still...